# Writing selenium webdriver fields to txt file

Tags: python, selenium

What i have done is write a small program to read JSON data and turn it in to selenium code.

Basic example code:

```
    def write_to_debug_file(self, debug_info):
        with open("debug/debug_file.txt", "a+") as file:
            file.write("%s\n" % debug_info)


    def get_identifier(self, identifier, html_identifier):
        final_identifier = ""
        if identifier == "id":
            final_identifier = self.driver.find_element_by_id(html_identifier) 
        elif identifier == "name":
            final_identifier = self.driver.find_element_by_name(html_identifier)
        return final_identifier


    def prepare_fields(self, url_or_identifier, html_identifier, name_this, action_to_take, username, password, email):
        #{
        #   "register": [
        #       "https:\/\/www.thesite.com\/register.php|0|0|SEND_URL",
        #       "name|username|0|SEND_USERNAME"
        #   ]
        #}
        selenium_field = ""
        if action_to_take == "SEND_URL":
            selenium_field == self.driver.get(url_or_identifier)
        elif action_to_take == "SEND_USERNAME":
            selenium_field == self.driver + self.get_identifier(url_or_identifier, html_identifier).send_keys(username)       
        else:
            pass
        return selenium_field


    def mode_register(self, username, password, email, captcha_key, _sleep, _json):       
        try:

            json_string = json.loads(_json)
            if "register" in json_string:
                for register in json_string["register"]:
                    register_parts = register.split("|")
                    selenium_action = self.prepare_fields(register_parts[0], register_parts[1], register_parts[2], register_parts[3], username, password, email)
                    self.write_to_debug_file("sleep(" + str(_sleep) + ")" + selenium_action)

            if "You have successfully created your account" in self.driver.page_source:
                return True
            else:
                return False

        except Exception as e: 
            self.print_exception()
```

The script works fine, what i'm having issues with is writing the `selenium_action` part to .txt file so i can debug it closely, currently i get the error:

***"selenium_action = self.prepare_fields(register_parts[0], register_parts[1], register_parts[2], register_parts[3], username, password, email)"): unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WebDriver' and 'NoneType'***

I cannot think of an easy way to write the fields to file, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use inbuilt logger package for writing any logs in a file for debug.
instead of writing your own function, you can simply use logging package.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.warning('This will get logged to a file')
```

There are multiple logging levels which can be used.

PS: The error that you got is because your function prepare_fields returned None.